# CSS grid ignores minimal width specified in minmax() in second column

Tags: css, css-grid

My grid :

```css
.MakerDataForm {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 24px 40px;
}
```

As you see in popup of developer tools, the left column's width is less that 320px.

[image]

[image]

Just for experiment, I tried to change to `minmax(320px, 640px)` - the grid has not changed.

My mistake or bug?

Comment: Your max may be smaller than your min, in this case your min may be ignore. Can you give a reproductive example of what you're doing?

Comment: @SeeoX, Thank you for the comment. "Your max may be smaller than your min" - I set max to "640px" - nothing changed. "Can you give a reproductive example of what you're doing?" - afraid no, because because a simple grid of simple div's will not reproduce the problem, while the reproducing the each component of grid takes too much time.

Comment: `minmax(320px, 1fr)` -> 1fr may be smaller than 320px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause.
Some children has `grid-column-start: span 2` which breaks the layout.

It must be [the new question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64098521/edit).