# Take 2 columns in 2-columns layout but not when 1-column layout in CSS grid without @media

Tags: css, css-grid

The desired layout for wide screens:

[image]

The desired layout for narrow screens:

[image]

Initial CSS:

```css
.Layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 24px 40px;
}
```

If I'll set `grid-column-start: span 2` for the third element, the layout will be simply broken (it' happen in [CSS grid ignores minimal width specified in minmax() in second column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64097914/css-grid-ignores-minimal-width-specified-in-minmax-in-second-column/64098274#64098274) question).

**Please don't use the media queries** because it will nullify the announced free-space-based responsiveness which became available in CSS grid.

> Grid has two extremely powerful features for dealing with changes in
> available space.
>
> <...>
>
> Layout that relies on media queries is tied to the view-port, this
> isn’t modular — components within a system need to be able to adapt to
> the space they have available.
>
> [Getting to know CSS Grid Layout](https://cm.engineering/getting-to-know-css-grid-layout-818e43ca71a5)

**Please say clearly: "it's impossible"** if you are sure that it so and skilled in CSS grid.

Comment: Do you want to use a grid-system as Bootstrap, Materialize ect. use? I would recommend to use, for instance, a 12-column grid system. I think this would that make a way easier.

Comment: @michaelT thank you for the comment. My answer: no. I find the pure grid solution or the confirmation of there is not such solution. By the way, the Boostrap grid is media-query-dependent!

Comment: I think that this is not possible to handle while using ````auto-fit````. What you want is exactly a 4-column grid, so I would prefer to use ````grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));````. For a good responsive experience you have to include media queries, this is a recommended way to handle this. **Edit:** Such a grid can be implemented very easily using ````SASS```` with just a few code lines.

Comment: @michaelT, Well, if I use the media queries, what if I need to reuse same component in wide main column and narrow sidebar? Because of component conception, the target component does not know about parent elements including their width, but the parent element must NOT know about child component infrastructure, so we can't redefine the child component classes based on parent CSS class. It was impossible to solve is by CSS until grid technology realize.

Comment: I did not exactly get it what you mean that the parent element must not know the child's structure. This should not really be necessary at any time. I just posted an example of a 4-column grid. Maybe it will be cleaer then.

Comment: is this acceptable: https://jsfiddle.net/g2aqv0bj/1/?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, yes! What kind of magic you have used this time?

Comment: I told the element to start from the first column and end to the last one (whataver the number is)

Comment: @TemaniAfif it's a bounty win. Would you please to copy-paste this comment with link to fiddle in answer field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `grid-column: 1/-1;`

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 24px 40px;
}

span {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.more {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="more"></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

That you can edit like below if you want to always have a maximum of 2 columns:

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max(240px,40vw), 1fr));
  grid-gap: 24px 40px;
}

span {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.more {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="more"></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll remember you as CSS genius. It's my fourth CSS problem that you elegantly solved.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I think I could handle your problem, but by using `flex` instead of `grid`. It is pretty tricky.

The main element is a class called `wrapper`, which has `display: flex;`.
You can insert your "grid items" there, now called `wrapper-container`.

I need this helper class to recreate the `grid-gap` property. Now I am using `padding` instead. Note that `padding` works a bit ditterent to `grid-gap` so I had to divide your gap by 2.

Each `wrapper-container` has a `wrapper-container__item` child, which contains your content. When you inspect these elements, you will notice, that they have at least a width of `240px` which is caused by their `min-width` property.

When you want an element to span over two "*columns*" add the class `wrapper-container__stretched` to the `wrapper-container`. It is applying `width: 100%` so that the element will be fullsized. Elements which do not have the class, has `flex: 1`, so they will stay next to each other (just like a 2-column grid).

Feel free to ask when there are any ambiguities.

**Codepen:**
[Responsive grid without media queries using flex-box](https://codepen.io/michaelkonstreu/pen/qBZGgxp)

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #dedede;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper-container{
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 20px;
}

.wrapper-container:not(.wrapper-container__stretched){
  flex: 1;
}

.wrapper-container.wrapper-container__stretched{
  width: 100% !important;
}

.wrapper-container__item{
  position: relative;
  min-width: 240px;
  min-height: 64px;
  width: 100%;
}


.red{
  background: #e53935;
}

.green{
  background: #388e3c;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <!-- Row 1 -->
  <div class="wrapper-container">
    <div class="wrapper-container__item green">Item 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-container">
    <div class="wrapper-container__item green">Item 2</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Row 2 -->
  <div class="wrapper-container wrapper-container__stretched">
    <div class="wrapper-container__item red">Item 3</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Row 3 -->
  <div class="wrapper-container">
    <div class="wrapper-container__item green">Item 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-container">
    <div class="wrapper-container__item green">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

A posible solution using flex, like MichaelT

```css
.layout {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
}


.innerlayout {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
}

span {
    background-color: green;
    height: 40px;
    min-width: 240px;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 15px 10px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.wide {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

#narrow {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
<div class="innerlayout">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="wide"></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="layout" id="narrow">
<div class="innerlayout">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="wide"></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
</div>
```