# css grid template columns with auto-fit but different sizes

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to have a grid as shown below. The problem is that I don't know how to combine the responsiveness and the auto generated columns with items that should have different widths.

I know that I can create a responsive grid with

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr))
```

or an implicit grid with different sizes like

```css
grid-template-columns: minmax(300px, 1.5fr)) minmax(300px, 1fr)) minmax(300px, 1fr)) minmax(300px, 1.5fr))
```

But that does not auto wrap on smaller screens.

How can I combine these? Can I use the `grid-column` attribute on an individual item to achieve this?

[image]

or is this a wrong approach and it would be better to use the flex system in this case?

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64098521/take-2-columns-in-2-columns-layout-but-not-when-1-column-layout-in-css-grid-with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use differently sized cells and also use `auto-fit` or `auto-fill` to define their behavior upon resizing.

However, to get precisely what your diagrams show, you can enclose your first two and last two `div`s in their own `div`, since taken together they are the same size, and use `auto-fill` on the outer `div`s:

```css
.container {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(500px, 1fr));
  gap: 5px;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  justify-items: stretch;
  gap: 5px;
}

.cell div {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.large {
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.small {
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="large">One</div>
    <div class="small">Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="small">Three</div>
    <div class="large">Four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So again, this wraps the first two cells and last two cells in their own respective `div`s, which creates two equivalent cells in the grid. You can then use an auto-fill on these outer `div`s.

You can make each of the two grid cells a flex display to format the two internal `div`s. Use `flex-grow` to size the internal `div`s by a 3:2 and 2:3 ratio, respectively.

It isn't a very flexible solution, because the outer `div`s still have to be sized in a repeatable pattern. But in your case, they are, so it solves this specific problem — assuming that you can change your HTML.